# How to customise ag-grid pagination

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

Is it possible to customize ag-grid pagination for angular.
Attached custom pagination image for reference.

[image]

```
<ag-grid-angular id="myGrid" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
 [rowData]="gridOptions.rowData"
    [columnDefs]="gridOptions.columnDefs" [pagination]="true"  [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"  (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [allowContextMenuWithControlKey]="true"
    [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems" >
</ag-grid-angular>


 onPageSizeChanged(event: any) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(Number(value));
  }
```

Comment: can be helpful in react: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77280975/how-to-add-ag-grid-react-pagination-rows-per-page-dropdown/77290339#77290339

Answer (score 2):

To create a customised pagination panel, you have to do the following two things:

1. Set `suppressPaginationPanel=true` to tell the grid to not show the default controls for pagination, as shown in the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#example-custom-pagination-controls)
2. Create a [Custom Status Bar Panel](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-status-bar/) to design your pagination panel as per your requirements. Note that this is an enterprise feature, so if you have a AG Grid license, you could contact the team via Zendesk for further support on this.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-pagination/#example-custom-pagination-controls