# How to add ag-grid react pagination rows per page dropdown

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

The default AG-Grid does not have a dropdown for pagination. How can I add the pagination drop shown like the image below?

[image]

---

```
<AgGridReact
  rowData={rowData}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  enableRangeSelection={true}
  rowSelection={'multiple'}
  statusBar={{
    statusPanels:
      [
        { statusPanel: 'agTotalRowCountComponent', align: 'center' },
        { statusPanel: 'agFilteredRowCountComponent' },
        { statusPanel: 'agSelectedRowCountComponent' },
        { statusPanel: 'agAggregationComponent' }
      ]
  }}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ag-Grid` does not have a default page size changer, but it is possible to create such a component. Normally, the page size changer is placed at the bottom of the grid. To achieve this, I typically add a statusPanel to statusPanels of statusBar property.

I've created the component, and [you can see preview at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo6Cv.jpg)

1. Create a PageSize component:

```js
export interface PaginationProps {
  api: GridApi;
}

const Pagination: FC<PaginationProps> = ({ api }) => {
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(api.paginationGetPageSize());

  const pageSizes = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50];

  const handleChangePageSize = (e) => {
    const value = Number(e.target.value);
    setPageSize(value);
    api.paginationSetPageSize(value);
  };

  return (
    <select
      value={pageSize}
      style={{ height: 40, minWidth: 100 }}
      onChange={handleChangePageSize}
    >
      {pageSizes.map((pageSize) => {
        return <option value={pageSize}>{pageSize}</option>;
      })}
    </select>
  );
};
```

2. Add `Pagination` component to components object and statusPanel to statusPanels.

**Please note that the statusPanel property value should match the name of your Pagination component.**

```js
<AgGridReact
  rowData={rowData}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  enableRangeSelection={true}
  rowSelection={"multiple"}
  components={{
    Pagination,
  }}
  statusBar={{
    statusPanels: [
      { statusPanel: "agTotalRowCountComponent", align: "center" },
      { statusPanel: "agFilteredRowCountComponent" },
      { statusPanel: "agSelectedRowCountComponent" },
      { statusPanel: "agAggregationComponent" },
      {
        statusPanel: "Pagination",
        align: "left",
      },
    ],
  }}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
/>
```

Finally, I would recommend studying the 'Row Pagination' section of the Ag-Grid documentation at [this link](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-pagination/).

Comment: I added my custom pagination component into my statuspanel but it doesn't work.

Comment: Probably  you forgot that add `Pagination` component to components property!